# What alternatives to Phonograph could have existed?

Tags: science-based, alternate-history, technological-development

Let's pretend for a moment humans have developed the same way they did in our reality until 1840's/1850's. 
What technological and scientifical advances could have been used as an alternative to inventing the Phonograph to record and play sound?

Would they have discovered first some kind of Magnetic recording device like the one used to record cassetes developed in the late quarter of the XXth century?

Would they have highly trained parrots or crows sold with your favourite tunes?

I can't stop thinking about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our world *[player pianos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Player_piano)* did not take off until the beginning of the 20th century. However, there is nothing in a player piano which could not have been available at the middle of the 19th. There were even most ingenious machines called *[reproducing pianos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_roll#Reproducing_pianos)* which recorded the performance of a pianist onto a [piano roll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_roll) for a player piano, which could then be multiplied by electromechanical machines.

In an alternate history the player piano could have been perfected much earlier, and the principle extended to other instruments controlled by keys, levers and pedals.

Unfortunately, while magnetic and optical sound *recording* was feasible with 19th century technology, *playback* was not. Mechanical sound recording as used by the original phonographs and gramophones has the advantage that is does not need electronic amplification for playback.

Comment: I am now, of course, tempted to 'invent' an opto-pneumatic means of recording and playing back sound.  Impractical/baroque for sure, but not obviously impossible.  I suspect the bandwidth would make recording recognizable speech very expensive, in media costs alone, alas.

Comment: So it would drive the technology into the direction of storing pyshically the position of the "note", and then replaying it, leading the same way to the magnetic and digital playback. super cool. i guess it makes sense.

Comment: @Catalyst: If you are into just-about-feasible signal amplification contraptions you will be delighted by the [Alexanderson alternator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexanderson_alternator) and its spiritual descendents the [amplidynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplidyne) (invented by the same Ernst Alexanderson, unfortunately much too late for the purposes of this question).

Comment: This answer makes me remember that the average wild west movie / book  is set in the times Gaudí was building the sagrada familia in my country. Mindrbreaking.

Answer (score 3):

Optical recording of sound https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_sound was developed around the same time as magnetic recording http://www.aes.org/aeshc/docs/recording.technology.history/magnetic4.html and is IMHO well worth a look.

The (cartoonified) explanation in the original Fantasia: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTM48pwoXAo
 gives the basic idea, if with some fanciful graphics.

Comment: awesome and completely unknown to me.

Comment: You're most welcome!  (Though I love the image of a line of trained parrots as an alternative.)

Comment: Let's see if anybody comes up with more awesome ideas. and Yes, a costume-wearing line of lady gaga new album's parrots, side to side with metallica's heavy metal crows, seems interesting.

Comment: Magnetic and optical _recording_ was feasible with 19th century technology; _playback_ was not.